# Java return statement concept

Tags: java, tree, return, binary-search-tree

So, I want to print a binary search tree in depth and I'm having the following code:

```
public String printBalancedBSTDepth(Node head) {

    if(head == null) {
        // do nothing
    }
    else 
        return head.value + " " + printBalancedBSTDepth(head.left) + " " + printBalancedBSTDepth(head.right);
}
```

When head == null, I don't want to print anything. Why is Java forcing me to add a return statement on every condition? I don't understand this need. In C language you put return where do you need, you're not forced to put it everywhere like in Java. And if I add "return "" " when head == null, my string will look something like this: `4 2 1   3   6 5   7`. Many unwanted spaces...

Comment: All distinct paths must return if the method declares a return type; it's pretty logical.

Comment: You can return an empty string -- `""`

Comment: Yes, but in this case I can't print the desired string because of that.

Comment: "*Why is Java forcing me to add a return statement on every condition?*" because your method is declared to return `String` so compiler tries to guarantee that you will return something for each scenario.

Comment: So what would be the solution for my code?

Comment: You could try throwing an exception, but that might be a bit excessive.

Answer (score 1):

If you are declaring that your method will return a `String`, then why don't you want to return one?

As others and you mentioned, you can return an empty string `""`. Or maybe you can return `null`. So to avoid the extra unwanted spaces, you can validate in your printing code, something like this:

```
if (result == null ) { // Or result.equals("")
   // Do nothing, or the necessary so those unwanted spaces aren't printed
}
```

Comment: how can it return null if it saids `String`?

Comment: If i return null, it will print "null" on the screen.

Comment: Because in fact, you are returning a reference. In this case a reference to a `String` object. If you return null, you are returning a reference that points to nothing. So, it's still valid.

Comment: @ConstantinDogaru as I mentioned, you would have to handle that specific case in your code (`if (result == null) ...`).